# How you get a color overlay on an image tag?

Tags: html, css

I'm having trouble getting a color overlay on an image tag. I'm not sure why. 
The background-color element doesn't appear to working.

```
!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <a href="http://google.com" class="image-container">
      <img class="image" src="https://img.favpng.com/14/3/12/hamburger-french-fries-fast-food-cheeseburger-small-bread-png-favpng-wz3jTDt4b8xrUBLJveLDpLFfm.jpg" alt="">
      <div class="overlay">
        <i class="fa fa-heart"></i>
        <i class="fa fa-comment"></i>
      </div>
    </a>
</body>
</html>
```

this is the mild css code.

```
.image:hover {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't assign a background color to an image. You can do a filter, and adjust it based on CSS [filter parameters](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/f/filter/).

However if you want a specific color to overlay the image you can overlay a `div` and give it a lighter opacity and change the background color on `hover`. I included both options in the example snippet.

```css
.image1 {
  width: 100px;
}
.image1:hover{
 -webkit-filter: contrast(4);
  filter: contrast(4);
}

.container{
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  position: relative;
}

.container img{
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  z-index: -1;
}

.overlay{
  opacity: 0.3; 
  width: inherit;
  height: inherit;
  z-index: 100;
  position: absolute;
}

.overlay:hover{
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<img class='image1' src='https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/03/04/22/35/head-659652_1280.png'/>

<div class='container'>
<div class='overlay'></div><img src='https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/03/04/22/35/head-659652_1280.png'/></div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Instead of keeping the class of image inside the image tag why don't you keep it on the outside.

```
    <div class="image">
       <img src="https://img.favpng.com/14/3/12/hamburger-french-fries-fast- 
       food-cheeseburger-small-bread-png-favpng-wz3jTDt4b8xrUBLJveLDpLFfm.jpg" alt="">
   </div>
```

also change your:

```
    !DOCTYPE html>
```

instead put:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
```

and you haven't connected your CSS 3 file. So do:

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="index1.css">
```

if your CSS 3 file name is "index1" that is.
But I would just photo shop a copy of it and then say in CSS 3:

```
    .image:hover {
       background-image: "where ever you file is";
    }
```